# Selecting count with other columns through joined tables (Oracle SQL)

Tags: sql, oracle, select, count

I have the following query that returns the number of orders a stock item has had:

```
select count(Orders.OrderID) from Stocks, Orders
where Stocks.StockID = Orders.StockID(+) group by Stocks.StockID;
```

This returns:

```
count(Orders.OrderID)
---------------------
0
1
2
0
1
...
```

However, I also want to display the name of the particular stock item alongside this query. So far, I have tried this, but the following error occurs...

```
select Stocks.Name, count(Orders.OrderID) from Stocks, Orders
where Stocks.StockID = Orders.StockID(+) group by Stocks.StockID;
```

The following error occurs:

```
select Stocks.Name, count(Orders.OrderID) from Stocks, Orders
       *
Error: not a GROUP BY expression.
```

This should return:

```
Name        count(Orders.OrderID)
----------  ---------------------
Item1       0
Item2       1
Item3       2
Item4       0
Item5       1
.....       ...
```

Can anyone help? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be sth like:

```
select Stocks.StockID,Stocks.Name, count(Orders.OrderID) 
from Stocks
left join Orders
  on Stocks.StockID = Orders.StockID  -- explicit outer join syntax
group by Stocks.StockID,Stocks.Name;  -- matching with select column list
```

Comment: Thanks very much! This seems to be the simplest solution.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you use the COUNT analytic function:

```
SELECT DISTINCT s.NAME,
       COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY s.STOCKID ORDER BY s.STOCKID) AS ON_ORDER
  FROM STOCKS s
  LEFT OUTER JOIN ORDERS o
    ON s.STOCKID = o.STOCKID
```

[dbfiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=3aae622e3eabab96b21242fcadf2f09d)

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be the following;

```
SELECT S.StockID, S.Name, Orders.[Count]
FROM Stocks AS S
    CROSS APPLY
    ( SELECT COUNT(*) AS [Count]
      FROM Orders AS O
      WHERE S.StockID = O.StockID
    ) AS Orders
```

:)

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=9f2fc53582f4544ccc1afef27331c23c

Answer (score 0):

From your description, it seems that you want to report one aggregate row for each stock name, or in other words group by the stock name:

```
select s.name as stock_name, count(o.orderid) as orders
from   stocks s
       left join orders o
            on  o.stockid = s.stockid
group by s.name;
```

That will give results like

```
STOCK_NAME  ORDERS
----------- ------
X              123
Y               45
Z                6
```

You can include other columns from Stocks such as the Stock ID if you want:

```
select s.stockid, s.name as stock_name, count(o.orderid) as orders
from   stocks s
       left join orders o
            on  o.stockid = s.stockid
group by s.stockid, s.name;
```

which will give results like

```
STOCKID  STOCK_NAME  ORDERS
-------- ----------- ------
1        X              123
2        Y               45
3        Z                6
```